# Adding canvas height, width through JS from html input value

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

so I want the user to enter 2 values (height and width) then I want to take the values and add them to a new canvas that I just created. I am getting the values however I am not sure ow to add them to style.height and style.width.

```js
var createNewCanvas = document.getElementById("createNewCanvas");
var resetCreateNewCanvas = document.getElementById("resetCreateNewCanvas");
var userInputWindow = document.getElementById("userInputWindow");
var enterCanvasHeight = document.getElementById("enterCanvasHeight");
var enterCanvasWidth = document.getElementById("enterCanvasWidth");




function createNewCanvass() {

    document.body.removeChild(userInputWindow);

var enterCanvasHeightt = enterCanvasHeight.value;
var enterCanvasWidthh = enterCanvasWidth.value;
    document.body.innerHTML = enterCanvasHeightt+":"+enterCanvasWidthh;

    var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    newCanvas.classList.add("canvasDesign");

  newCanvas.style.height = enterCanvasHeightt;
    newCanvas.style.width = enterCanvasWidthh;


    document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);


}

createNewCanvas.addEventListener('click', createNewCanvass);
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(46, 45, 45);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.createNewCanvas {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.7);

  width: 300px;
}
.enterCanvasHeight, .enterCanvasWidth {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.canvasDesign {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Canvas</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h2>Canvas</h2>
        <menu></menu>
    </header>
    <div class="createNewCanvas" id="userInputWindow">
        Please enter the size of your canvas in pixels(px) and then click "create"<br><br>
        <form>
            <input type="number" id="enterCanvasHeight" placeholder="height"> : <input type="number" id="enterCanvasWidth" placeholder="width"><br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Create" id="createNewCanvas">
            <input type="button" value="Reset" id="resetCreateNewCanvas"><br>
        </form>
    </div>


    <footer></footer>
    <script src="Script/createNewCanvas.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding +"px" to the style.height and style.width

```
newCanvas.style.height = enterCanvasHeightt+"px";
newCanvas.style.width = enterCanvasWidthh+"px";
```

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Just to let you know that setting style width and height just sets the canvas display size. To change the canvas resolution you also need to set the canvas width and height properties `canvas.width` & `canvas.height` which are numbers and can not be postfixed.

Comment: yes, yes I know that :) I just started this project and display size was first thing I wanted to do. Thank you!